# ruining EasyRTC server using iisnode

Tags: node.js, webrtc, iisnode, easyrtc

EasyRTC is one of the best available opensource WebRTC solutions that runs in node.js! I have manged to run it on node.js on my system but my application is in Asp.net so I've been trying to run it using under IIS using iisnode! but for some reason I haven't been able to make it work! running this application in node.js i use `node server.js` to start the server but in IIS when i set the default page to `server.js` to start the application it wond work! 
this is result by using

**nodejs:**
[image]

**nodejs result:** (working properly)
[image]

**IISNODE Result:**
looks like it's not even running it !

[image]

Comment: I do not clearly understand your problem. But please note that, easyrtc server is based on nodejs but client side do not use nodejs. To know how client side communicate with easyrtc server see the onStartup function in easyrtc_default_event_listenes.js in lib folder. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This error is due to lack required module for easyRTC. type in node command prompt "npm install" It will install all dependency module. And after that try to run server. I hope It will work for you.